# Python Kivy: render 3d scene

Tags: 3d, kivy

I'm using Kivy and I want to render a 3D scene where I could do animation and move the camera.  But I have no knowledge with OpenGL to render the scene directly in Kivy.  Does anyone know a library to do it simply?
I found a lot, but nothing was compatible with Kivy.
**Thank you in advance !**

Comment: There are a few Kivy 3d examples around, and some components of 3d toolkits, but nothing especially well maintained.

Comment: The typical example of a 3D scene in Kivy is [Monkey Head](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__3Drendering__main__py.html#). If you download Kivy from [kivy.org](https://kivy.org/#download), the code is included in the `examples` folder.

Comment: Yes, i knom. But i've no knowledge with opengl, so it's very difficult to understand for me. It's a shame that there is no professional library for this.